# Overlay AJAX text on PHP while loop

Tags: php, html, ajax

I've been searching the web but I can't seem to find any solution... I posted the question before, but I'm trying to add new code...

I have the following code -->

A PHP page with a form that self-submits with simplified code:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        mail($to, $subject, $newMessage, $headers);

    }
} ?>

<?php if (!isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    <form action="$PHP_SELF" method="post">
        <input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" />
        <textarea name="message" id="nbody"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send newsletter" />
    </form>
}else{
    echo "All mail processed";
} ?>
```

While processing the SQL request and sending mails, I'd like to show some kind of text overlayed that shows the email sending progress (like "sending email 1 out of 100).

I think AJAX could probably do that, but I've tried many solutions without exit... I use jQuery library.

Thanks!!

Comment: Hi! Can I suggest that you go accept some answers on your previous questions, if they've helped you?

Comment: I did accept, but I got nothing that helped much ;)